# Mysql Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update" en una tabla

Tags: mysql, sql

//Tengo 6 tablas, el error sale al crear la sexta tabla//

```
CREATE TABLE departamento(

    id_departamento int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

    nombre varchar(45)

    )

CREATE TABLE trabajadores(

    cod_trabajar int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

    ci_trab int NOT null,

    nss int(5),

    nombre varchar(45),

    apellido varchar(45),

    telefono int(10),

    direccion varchar(10),

    id_departamento int NOT null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_id_departamento FOREIGN KEY (id_departamento) REFERENCES departamento (id_departamento)

    )

CREATE TABLE categoria(

    id_categoria int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

    nombre varchar(45)

    )

CREATE TABLE contratos(

    n_contrato int NOT null PRIMARY KEY,

    fecha_inicial date,

    fecha_final date,

    id_categoria int NOT null,

    cod_trabajar int NOT null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_id_categoria FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria) REFERENCES categoria (id_categoria),

    CONSTRAINT fk_cod_trabajar FOREIGN KEY (cod_trabajar) REFERENCES trabajadores (cod_trabajar)

   )
```

//Pero al crear la 6ta. tabla//

```
CREATE TABLE nomina(

    salario int NOT null,

    fecha date,

    n_contrato int not null,

    cod_trabajar int NOT null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_n_contrato FOREIGN KEY (n_contrato) REFERENCES contratos (n_contrato),

    CONSTRAINT fk_cod_trabajar FOREIGN KEY (cod_trabajar) REFERENCES trabajadores (cod_trabajar)

   )
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1005 - No puedo crear tabla `prueba1`.`nomina` (Error: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") (Detalles…)

//¿Cual sería la solucion a esto?//

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que esto se deba a que ha nombrado al menos una restricción con el mismo identificador que una columna:

Me refiero a esta parte

```
CONSTRAINT fk_n_contrato FOREIGN KEY (n_contrato) REFERENCES contratos (n_contrato) ,

    CONSTRAINT fk_cod_trabajar FOREIGN KEY (cod_trabajar) REFERENCES trabajadores (cod_trabajar)
```

En cambio si intentas de este modo.
Concatenando el nombre de la tabla en la llave veras que no marca error ya que no se llamara igual que a los campos que ahi tienes.

```
CREATE TABLE nomina(

    salario int NOT null,

    fecha date,

    n_contrato int not null,

    cod_trabajar int NOT null,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Contrato_n_contrato FOREIGN KEY (n_contrato) REFERENCES contratos (n_contrato) ,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Trabajar_cod_trabajar FOREIGN KEY (cod_trabajar) REFERENCES trabajadores (cod_trabajar)

   );
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que en la tabla "nomina" estas creando la FOREIGN KEY con el mismo nombre que tiene la FOREIGN KEY en la tabla "contratos" más específicamente estas duplicando el nombre de la FOREIGN KEY llamada "fk_cod_trabajar"